# Missing data from dplyr filter (multiple conditions) function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to filter my data set using multiple conditions (exact + partial matches). But the `filter` function from `dplyr` only returns part of the results that matched the conditions. Here is an example:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("6/24/2020", "6/24/2020", "6/24/2020", "6/24/2020", "6/25/2020", "6/25/2020"), 
                      Market = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), Salesman = c("MF", "RP", "FR", "FR", "MF", "MF"), 
                      Product = c("* Apple", "Apple", "* Banana", "* Orange", "* Apple", "* Banana"), Quantity = c(20L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 15L), 
                      Price = c(1L,1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), Cost = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

The following codes supposed to return row `1` and `3`, but it only returned the first row:

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  filter(Salesman == c("MF","FR"),
         Market == "A",
         grepl("* ",Product))
```

It seems `grepl("* ",Product)` caused the problem, but I need it to return `Product` that contains `*` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==` works onlyy with a vector of length 1.  If more than that, it will recycle and results in unexpected output.  Here, we need `%in%` for the first case, and in `grepl`, the `*` is a metacharacter (zero or more).  Either escape (`\\*`) or place it in square brackets (`[*]`) or use `fixed = TRUE` to literally evaluate.  The `fixed = TRUE` may be faster so, here we are using that

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     filter(Salesman %in% c("MF", "FR"),
            Market == "A",  
            grepl("*", Product, fixed = TRUE))
#   Date Market Salesman  Product Quantity Price Cost
#1 6/24/2020      A       MF  * Apple       20     1  0.5
#3 6/24/2020      A       FR * Banana       20     2  0.5
```

---

If the `*` should be picked up from the start (`^`) of the string, then we can escape it `*`

```
df1 %>% 
     filter(Salesman %in% c("MF", "FR"),
            Market == "A",  
            grepl("^\\*", Product))
#       Date Market Salesman  Product Quantity Price Cost
#1 6/24/2020      A       MF  * Apple       20     1  0.5
#3 6/24/2020      A       FR * Banana       20     2  0.5
```